# C++ values from struct creating newlines in CSV file

Tags: c++, csv

I am very new to C++, and currently am attempting to create a simple user interface which will do the following:

- Check if a CSV file already exists with the given name
- Create that file if it does not exists, and write the headers
- Ask user for information, store in struct
- Write data to CSV file when done

The issue I am facing is that when the program ends, and writes the data to the CSV file it creates newlines for each struct variable I am writing. I would like the program to just write all data on one line with comma separated format.

Example code:
struct.h

```cpp
#ifndef struct_h
#define struct_h

#include "string"
namespace RB
{

    struct Values
    {
        std::string event;
        std::string town;
        std::string state;
        std::string date;
    };
}; // namespace

#endif /* struct_h */
```

create.h

```cpp
#ifndef create_h
#define create_h

#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

namespace RB
{

    int createFile()
    {
        time_t t = time(nullptr);    // the current time
        struct tm gmt = *gmtime(&t); // structured time in GMT

        const int year = 1900 + gmt.tm_year;
        static const char *filename = "results_";

        if (std::ifstream((filename + std::to_string(year) + ".csv").c_str()))
        {
            std::cout << "File Found, appending to file " << (filename + std::to_string(year) + ".csv").c_str() << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "No file with name " << (filename + std::to_string(year) + ".csv").c_str() << "\ncreating file...\n" << std::endl;
            std::ofstream ofile((filename + std::to_string(year) + ".csv").c_str());
            ofile << "Event" << ","
                  << "Town" << ","
                  << "State" << ","
                  << "Date" << "\n";
            ofile.flush();
            ofile.close();
        };
        return 0;
    };
}

#endif /* create_h */
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "struct.h"
#include "create.h"

int main()
{
    // Run Create before continuing
    int c = RB::createFile();

    struct RB::Values revent;
    // Get Event Name
    std::cout << "Starting to enter data for race event...\n" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "What was the name of the event: ";
    std::cin >> revent.event;


    // Get Event Town
    std::cout << "What town was the race run in: ";
    std::cin >> revent.town;

    // Get Event City
    std::cout << "What state was the race run in: ";
    std::cin >> revent.state;

    // Get Event Date
    std::cout << "When was the race run: ";
    std::cin >> revent.date;


    time_t t = time(nullptr);    // the current time
    struct tm gmt = *gmtime(&t); // structured time in GMT

    const int year = 1900 + gmt.tm_year;
    static const char *filename = "results_";

    if (std::ifstream((filename + std::to_string(year) + ".csv").c_str()))
    {
        std::ofstream ofile((filename + std::to_string(year) + ".csv").c_str(), std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
        ofile << revent.event << ",";
        ofile << revent.town << ",";
        ofile << revent.state << ",";
        ofile << revent.date;
        ofile.close();
    };
    return 0;
}
```

Sample Output:

```
Event,Town,State,Date
CapRock
,Turkey
,Texas
,March 9
```

I assume this is something simple I am doing wrong, but cannot seem to figure it out on my own.

Comment: ofile << revent.event << "," << revent.town << "," << << revent.state << "," << revent.date;

Comment: Line break is in your input file. Please show us  the file where you get the revent from

Comment: @OmidCompSCI  Unfortunately, I have already tried that method, but it resulted in the same outcome.

Comment: @Aleksandrus revent is pointing to my struct.h file which is the first code block in my question.

Comment: Show the sample data file you read. Also, aside, for csv it's recommended you put each entry in double quotes, e.g., "March 9". This will also help show where your line break is coming from.

Comment: @lurker   I am not reading a data file, I am asking the user for input and then using `cin >>` to store in the specific struct value. I will try wrapping my values in double quotes to see if that shows where my issue is. Thanks

Comment: Ok. But put the double quotes in as I also indicated. You're probably capturing the line terminator from the user input. You may have to trim it off.

Comment: @lurker  Thanks, you were correct with the line terminator from the user input. I ended up using `std::regex_replace(string, "\n+", "");` to remove the line terminator. If you add an answer I will accept it as correct.

Comment: A regex is a bit over-kill to trim off space at the end. Also, your particular regex would remove newlines out of the middle of the string. You probably don't have those, but it's still an unintended action. A more precise regex would be `std::regex_replace(string, "\n+$", ""
)`.

Comment: @lurker   What would you recommend over a regex for this scenario?

Comment: Good question! The `std::string` class doesn't have a specific method for trimming a string as in some languages' string classes. There's a verbose way of doing it which is more specific than the regex which erases any trailing spaces (as determined by `std::isspace`): `myString.erase(std::find_if(myString.rbegin(), myString.rend(), [](unsigned char ch) { return !std::isspace(ch); }).base(), myString.end());`